# spark jdbc salesforce connection: invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, salesforce, connection, cdata

i am getting jdbc error when connecting from spark to salesforce from windows... using the cdata jdbc driver

i am sure i can login to salesforce with username/password. in addition, reset my password which generate a new security token. have no idea how i can get above error...

details below:

```
spark-shell --jars "c:\cdata\cdata.jdbc.salesforce.jar"
```

```scala
val = spark.sqlContext
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url","jdbc:salesforce:User=myusername;Password=mypassword;SecurityToken=*****;")
    .option("driver","cdata.jdbc.salesforce.SalesforceDriver")
    .load()
```

i have retried resetting password and regenerating security token(in that order) few times. still getting that error. i am sure my username password is correct because i can login.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
  at XcoreXsalesforceX230X8565.ycb.a(Unknown Source)
  at XcoreXsalesforceX230X8565.ycb.a(Unknown Source)
  at XcoreXsalesforceX230X8565.scb.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.getQueryOutputSchema(JDBCRDD.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.

Comment: Do you actually see failed attempts in your user's login history in setup? Maybe you're hammering against wrong org (sandbox vs prod, another sandbox...). Can you use same username and pass from say Data Loader?